# How to generate token for two classes using JWT symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, authentication, jwt

I have two entities `User` and `Merch`.

A `User` uses a form and authenticates with his username and password.

A `Merch` uses an iPad app and authenticates with their `merchCode` (integer eg:11) and password.

With JWT Authentification I can generate a token for `User`.
The problem is I don't know what do to generate a token for `Merch`, too.

I want to use two different paths:

- `/api/login_check_user`
- `/api/login_check_merch`

for Merch I want to return a Response contain token + marchId

my security.yaml

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: argon2i
        App\Entity\Merch:
                algorithm: auto


    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:  ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path:               /api/login_check_user
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure

        refresh:
          pattern:  ^/api/token/refresh
          stateless: true
          anonymous: true

        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            stateless: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
        main:
            anonymous: true

    # access_control:
    #     - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    #     - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/validator, roles: ROLE_VALIDATOR }
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/token/refresh, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

With Lexik, we can override the response with events:
https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/2-data-customization.md#eventsjwt_created---adding-custom-data-or-headers-to-the-jwt

So you sould have only one firewall